# How do I make a variable in a list recognizable as a number?

Tags: python, list

Here is my code:

```
list1 =  "SP   " , "Total Sales   " , "Total Commission"
print("  ".join(list1))
listA = ["103  " , "500"]
listB = "104  " , "25000"
listC = "201  " , "51000"
listD = "319  " , "100000"
listE = "367  " , "12599"
listF = "388  " , "12600"
listG = "435  " , "292000"
print("  ".join(listA))
print("  ".join(listB))
print("  ".join(listC))
print("  ".join(listD))
print("  ".join(listE))
print("  ".join(listF))
print("  ".join(listG))
if  0 < (listA[1]) < 50999:
    print ("yes")
```

I am getting this error: `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`

I need to be able to check the number in `(listA[1])` to see if it is greater than 0 and less than 50999 and I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-overflow, please copy paste your code with 4 indentation from next time like this

Answer (score 4):

If you have

```
listA = ["103  " , "500"]
```

you can simply use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to change it to a list of integers:

```
listA = [int(item) for item in listA]
```

which can then be compared with other integers.

However, you shouldn't be using seven (or more) separate lists. Better do something like:

```
lists = [["103  " , "500"],
         ["104  " , "25000"],
         ["201  " , "51000"],
         ["319  " , "100000"],
         ["367  " , "12599"],
         ["388  " , "12600"],
         ["435  " , "292000"],
        ]
```

and then access the sublists as `lists[0]` instead of `listA`, `lists[1]` instead of `listB`, etc.

Comment: You could alternatively use `map(int, listA)` instead of the list comprehension if you're feeling uber functional :)

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas: Yes, but listcomps are considered much more pythonical. Guido even considered removing `map` and `filter` from the language entirely and only seems to have kept them for backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string and an integer.

You should do something like

```
if  0 < int(listA[1]) < 50999:
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it into int(). This will convert the string to an int.

```
0 < int(listA[1]) < 50999:
```